# Error coming while loading the recyclerView multiple times with different datasets

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-seekbar

In my application, I have a **spinner** and a **recyclerView**. Based on the items **selected in the spinner**,different list of items will be **shown in the recyclerView**.

Initially based on the item selection on the spinner, I am getting perfect data in the recyclerView. However after **4-5 times changing** the data in the spinner and getting correponding list in the recyclerView, I am getting the following **exception** with my application crashing down:

**The Exception:**

```
      java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:2).state:2
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5456)
```

**My Code:**

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,dcuName);
        dcuSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        slcList = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.addedSlcList);
        handleDCURequest = new handleDCURequest();

        dcuSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id)
            {
                Query refQuery1 =  ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(dcuName.get(position));
                refQuery1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                    {
                        slcList.getRecycledViewPool().clear();

                        Log.d("SpinnerAdd2", dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        dcuIDVal = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<slcObject, viewHolder>(slcObject.class,  R.layout.single_slc_row,
                                viewHolder.class,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("JSON").child("StreetLightcontrol").child( dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("DeviceList")) {
                            @Override
                            protected void populateViewHolder(final viewHolder viewHolder, slcObject model, int position)
                            {
                                //expand collapse
//
                                viewHolder.vis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v)
                                    {
                                        // ViewAnimationsUtils.expand(viewHolder.inv);
                                        viewHolder.collapse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        viewHolder.inv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }
                                });
                                viewHolder.collapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v)
                                    {
                                        // ViewAnimationsUtils.collapse(inv);
                                        viewHolder.inv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        viewHolder.collapse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                });
                                final String slcIDVal= adapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();
                                viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());

                                viewHolder.onOff.setClickable(false);
                                viewHolder.onOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v)
                                    {
                                        if(viewHolder.onOff.isChecked())
                                        {
                                            viewHolder.onOff.setChecked(false);
                                            handleDCURequest.slc_onoff((Context)myContext,1, slcIDVal,dcuIDVal, viewHolder.onOff, viewHolder.dimming);
                                           //Toast.makeText(myContext,"Turned On",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            viewHolder.onOff.setChecked(true);
                                            handleDCURequest.slc_onoff((Context)myContext,0, slcIDVal,dcuIDVal, viewHolder.onOff,viewHolder.dimming);
                                           // Toast.makeText(myContext,"Turned Off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    });

                                viewHolder.dimming.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                                    int originalProgress;
                                    @Override
                                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
                                    {
                                        if(seekBar.isShown()) {
                                            viewHolder.dimming.setEnabled(false);
                                            handleDCURequest.slc_dimming((Context) myContext, slcIDVal, seekBar.getProgress(), originalProgress, dcuIDVal, viewHolder.dimming);
//
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                        originalProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                                        if(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                                        {
                                            if(seekBar.isShown() && fromUser)
                                            {
//                                                progress= (progress/10)*10;
//                                                //ProgressUtil.showProgressDialog(progressDialog);
//                                                Log.d("Seek", String.valueOf(progress));
//                                                viewHolder.dimming.setEnabled(false);
//                                                handleDCURequest.slc_dimming((Context)myContext,slcIDVal,progress, originalProgress,dcuIDVal,viewHolder.dimming);
//                                                //adapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).child("Percentage").setValue(progress);

                                                //viewHolder.showProgress.setText(progress+"%");
                                            }
                                        }



                                    }
                                });

                                viewHolder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                       @Override
                                                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                                                           final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(myContext);
                                                                           dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                                                           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_slc);
                                                                           dialog.setCancelable(false);
                                                                           Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                                                                           if (window == null) return;
                                                                           WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                                                                           lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                                                                           lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                                                                           lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                                                                           lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                                                                           dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                                                                           final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.slcNameu);
                                                                           final EditText lat = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.slcLatu);
                                                                           final EditText lng = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.slcLngu);
                                                                           final EditText note = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.slcNoteu);
                                                                           final EditText id = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.slcIDu);
                                                                           TextView cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelu);
                                                                           TextView update = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.updateSlc);
                                                                           update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                               @Override
                                                                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                                                                   final String oldSlcIDVal= adapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();
                                                                                   Map mParent = new HashMap();
                                                                                   mParent.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                                                                                   mParent.put("lat",lat.getText().toString());
                                                                                   mParent.put("log",lng.getText().toString());
                                                                                   mParent.put("note",note.getText().toString());


//
                                                                               }
                                                                           });
                                                                           cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                               @Override
                                                                               public void onClick(View v)
                                                                               {
                                                                                   dialog.dismiss();
                                                                               }
                                                                           });
                                                                       }
                                                                   });


                                        viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v)
                                    {
                                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(myContext);
                                        dialog.setTitle("Delete Slc?");
                                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.delete_slc);
                                        dialog.setCancelable(false);
                                        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                                        if(window == null) return;
                                        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                                        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                                        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                                        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                                        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                                        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                                        TextView delete = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.deleteSlc);
                                        final String key= adapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();
                                        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v)
                                            {
                                                // int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                                                Log.d("positionVal",viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()+"");
                                                handleDCURequest.delete_slc((Context)myContext,slcIDVal,viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), dcuIDVal,adapter);

                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        });


                                        TextView dialogButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.canceld);
                                        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                                        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v)
                                            {
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        });

                                        dialog.show();

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        };
                        slcList.setLayoutManager(llm);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        slcList.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too long, perhaps divide it into chunks but Based on the Explanation and Exception you are getting:-

- **Explanation**: "Initially based on the item selection on the spinner, I
  am getting perfect data in the recyclerView. However after 4-5 times
  changing the data in the spinner"
- **Exception**: "IndexOutOfBoundsException"

This perfectly indicates that Your RecycleView cant get the data to populate anymore, the reference passed to it is out of the allocated data bound (Example the data you have is 20 but you are passing a refrence of 25).

I suggest you use `Log.d("Data",data.size);` to pin point the actual data size or use `breakpoints` or refactor your code so its easy for us to pin point it. :)

regards.

Comment: Hi, mostly after the adapter started, inside populateViewHolder is the code for the recyclerView Adapter.

Comment: This issue is very erratic. Its coming unexpectedly while other times its not there.

Comment: Its usually like that, I had similar issue before on List upon loading and reloading the list keeps growing I never cleared the adapter data hence the position and data is unstable, I suspect the issue is the same your case I have pinpoint you only call clear on your RecycleView but never on the Spinner that Supplies data to the RecleView on the first palce: Try call .clear(); and probably .notifyDataSetChanged(); or just do a data reload after calling .clear(). If it any works please accept my answer for future reference and for others facing similar issues. Cheers.